# Changing background of datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am able to change background of datacell through following C# code -

```
    private void Retrieve_rows(object item)
    {
        DataRow row = mygrid.GetContainerFromItem(item) as DataGrid.DataRow;

        if (row != null)
        {
            SolidColorBrush redColor = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);

            foreach (DataGrid.DataCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                 var dc = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(((DataGrid.Cell)(cell)).ParentRow)).DataContext;   

              // get my custom object and change color if IsBlank value is set to true
                MyRowObject rowObject = dc as MyRowObject;

                for (int counter = 0; counter < rowObject.values.Count; counter++)
                {
                        if (rowObject.values[counter].IsBlank == true)
                            row.Cells[counter].Background = redColor;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

But with this code, application performance degrades to great extent. Is there any way to convert above code to XAML Triggers / or any other way to improve the performance of the grid.

Answer (score 3):

Since you need two dynamic values to determine the background color of the cell (`ColumnIndex` and the `ValuesList`), you'll need to use a `MultiConverter` which accepts these two values and returns a color.

For example,

```
if ValueList[ColumnIndex].IsBlank)
    Return Colors.Red; // Might be Brushes.Red too, can't remember
else
    Return Colors.White;
```

The Trigger can then be applied implicitly to all `DataGridCells` with a style that doesn't have a Key specified

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Column.DisplayIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                <Binding Path="ValueList" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I might have the `RelativeSource` syntax wrong in the `Column.DisplayIndex` binding of the `MultiBinding`, however the binding should point to `Self`, which is the `DataGridCell`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the WPF world ;)

You could try this:

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
   </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Cheers,

Sebi

Comment: Hi Sebi, thanks for the reply. but I already tried following xaml code which does not work . <MultiDataTrigger> <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions> <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=FieldName}" Value="value"/> <Condition Binding="{Binding IsBlank}" Value="true"/> </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions> <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/> </MultiDataTrigger>

Comment: please be more specific - what do you intend to do with that multidatatrigger? it seems a bit off topic...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because the datagrid only defines structure not style.
I use rectangles in a grid cell.

```
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" Text="test"></TextBox>
```